# How do I view a specific date in my Google Chrome history?

Tags: google-chrome, history

I was looking for a specific page and found it in my history search, but I can't see the entry in the context of how I found the page in the first place. I tried to search by date (the only metadata I have on the page from the search) but the usual formats aren't working. How can I view a previous date without clicking "Older >" over and over again? Can I jump to a date somehow?

Comment: You could have clicked the "older" link and then manually edit the page number in the URL. But they made it even more stupid now... they removed the "Older" link!! They continue making the software stupider and stupider.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I would recommend that rather than using a third party extension just browse your activity from https://myactivity.google.com.

You can use the `+Filter by date & product` option below `Search` to filter your history by dates and various Google products (see the screenshot below).

[image: Google history search]

---

*In prior versions of Chrome, you could also find a link to this history at the top of your Chrome history saying, `Your Google Account may have other forms of browsing history at history.google.com.` However, this link has been removed in current versions.*

---

Comment: The important detail missing from this answer is that https://history.google.com allows you to search by date.

Comment: This requires being signed in, and does not work if a user has opted out or was not signed in for their browsing.

Comment: The bundled aggregation view of items in Google My Activity is really nice.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work if you pause your activities, and I have paused them all due to security concerns.

Comment: Seems if you use a passphrase for Sync, it's not possible to view the history via that website. Also, Chrome doesn't even show up in that product filter list for me.

Comment: This is completely different from my browser history. I don't have the history on the cloud.

Comment: This doesn't have Chrome history.

Comment: And what about if I haven't invited Google to spy on my every move?

Comment: Chrome is no longer listed as an 'app' that you can include in the filter

Comment: I wish I could use some of my stack overflow points to downvote this answer

Comment: Working for me, thank you very much, saved a lot of scrolling back.

Answer (score 20):

I found the ["history trends" extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/history%20trends) (by Randy Lauen) for Google Chrome in the "Chrome Web Store" extremely helpful!

It lets you view the previous 3 months worth of data with lots of various filters to refine the results, and also breaks it down by day (and you don't have to go through a bunch of dates to get to the one you want.)
It gives data for individual things like domains, url's, unique urls, percentage of visits to a certain site, number of visits total for a day or for all three months,  has a list of top ten busiest days, gives daily stats average and median sites visited, there are several bar and pie graphs showing things like transition types, number of visits per month compared to each other, number of visits per each day of the month or day of the week and even the time of day!

You can click right on the graphs, so if you want to know what sites or how many sites you view at 10pm it will give you the stats for and compare each day of the week for the total for all 3 months or for a given week...highly recommended!

Answer (score 10):

Add [Better History](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-history/egehpkpgpgooebopjihjmnpejnjafefi/related) chrome extension and you can search the history through date without clicking 'older' link again and again

[image: Better-history-extension]

Comment: This is a duplicate of the top answer

Comment: No, it's not.. Check the answer

Comment: Could it work retrospectively?

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It's an awful extension to actually use, UX-wise, but it gives the important info.

Answer (score 8):

I've tried out both the Better History & History Trends Extensions and got good results from both, so you should check them out to see which works better for you. Checking the Chrome store periodically is a good idea since new extensions- most free of charge- arrive frequently. Case in point- the History Trends author created a new extension [History Trends Unlimited](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-trends-unlimited/pnmchffiealhkdloeffcdnbgdnedheme) that goes even further by creating & linking to a local database so you can go around Chrome's 3 month time limit. Hope you get good results whichever you choose!

Answer (score 7):

For those seeking an open-source solution, check out [Richard Gong](https://richgong.com/)'s [History by Date](https://github.com/richgong/history-by-date).

[image: Screenshot of History by Date]

https://github.com/richgong/history-by-date

Answer (score 4):

[Chrome Better History](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-better-history/aadbaagbanfijdnflkhepgjmhlpppbad/related)

Note that there is a difference between ["**Chrome** Better History"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-better-history/aadbaagbanfijdnflkhepgjmhlpppbad/related) and ["Better History"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-history/egehpkpgpgooebopjihjmnpejnjafefi/related).

Comment: "Note that there is a difference between Chrome Better History and Better History." A comparison would be helpful then

Comment: Does not exist on the extensions store anymore.

Comment: Also, answers that just say "use this extension" are not the best, for this very reason...

Comment: "Chrome Better History" has been delisted and is no longer available