# How to conveniently view all browsing history?

Tags: google-chrome, history, google-search

I want to be able to view my browsing history like a calendar. I pick a date and see what I did during that day. How do I do this instead of scrolling on and on until I find that date which would take forever

Comment: The best way is to use google's MyActivity site as described at https://superuser.com/questions/739001/how-do-i-view-a-specific-date-in-my-google-chrome-history

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I view a specific date in my Google Chrome history?](https://superuser.com/questions/739001/how-do-i-view-a-specific-date-in-my-google-chrome-history)