# I want to delete Chrome history from Mac, older than a certain date...how to do it?

Tags: google-chrome, history

From Chrome Privacy settings I can delete history from the last weeks or months, or all history.

However, I would like to delete history older than one year as it starts to take a lot of GB on my Mac (so stupid I bought 256GB SSD...)

How can I do it?

Actually to be honest  I would like to bring down the size of Chrome Service Worker folder which I believe contains Browsing data among other things. It takes 5GB which for my situation is too much. The Browsing data seems to be the biggest one, as images only take 200MB and the rest are cookies or passwords...

Any suggestion welcome

Comment: See the answers from this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/739001/how-do-i-view-a-specific-date-in-my-google-chrome-history) to select specific hystory dates, then delete the dates older than a year

Comment: yes, but if I understand, in that way you'll delete also your history from your web account not only from your pc. It's not possible to delete only local history and keep the full history into your online account?

Comment: Service Workers are a modern web technology and are not associated with history.

Answer (score 0):

History will not use that much storage. Try clearing your cookies and cache in chrome. These things are what uses all the storage, Not history.